# Generating an hash function for unordered_map with custom Key

Tags: c++, hash

I need to save a set of pointers in an unordered_map, using as key a 
`std::vector<std::vector<int>>` since it's what makes my elements unique (in particular the inner vector all have the same size, and if the inner vectors are in a different order, it's still the same element).

I started looking around but having never done something like this, I got a bit lost around the various opportunities, e.g. creating a template for an hash function, calculating an unique value from those vectors and using it directly as key, hash boost library.

I'm not looking for someone to solve this problem for me, but just for someone who can direct me somewhere where I can study to figure this out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would at least keep the inner part sorted if it doesn't change to the way the contents are seen. This will later help when calculating the hash value.

Comment: @BoR Yes I already thought to order them if the "unordering" would have been a problem,but unfortunately that's not my main issue. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to do something along the lines of `using Key = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
using Ptr = void*;
std::unordered_map<Key,Ptr> myMap;
`?

Comment: You should sort the vectors as mentioned. After that, simply use boost's hash_combine (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) and build your own hash function. However, if your map is bigger, I would recommend another hash map since the standard unordered_map is pretty slow. Google's dense_hash_map is fast.

Comment: @BoR yes that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @Unterfliege Thanks a lot, I will try and let you know!

Comment: I think it would be better if you can add the problem you want to solve. In case `unordered_map` is not the best choice.